# Paypal IPN subscription (php)

Tags: php, paypal, subscription, paypal-ipn

I am trying to set up a subscription using Paypal and their IPN system for days now.
I could not understand most tutorials and finally found one that made sense to me.

With help of Sean on here I have changed the code slightly but still no luck.

To create the subscription button, I use the following code:

```
<form action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@mydomain.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="NL">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Mydomain.com Abonnement">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.mydomain.com/pp-ipn-handler.php">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mydomain.com/ppsuccess.php">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="'. $username .'">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Betaalperiode"><strong>Kies uw betaalperiode:</strong></td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="Per maand">Per maand : &euro;25.00 EUR</option>
    <option value="Per jaar">Per jaar : &euro;240.00 EUR</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Per maand">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="25.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_period0" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="option_frequency0" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Per jaar">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="240.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_period1" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" name="option_frequency1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/nl_NL/NL/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal, de veilige en complete manier van online betalen.">
</form>
```

To handle the ipn response I have a file named pp-ipn-handler.php with the following code:

```
<?php
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
// assign posted variables to local variables
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
// $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$payment_currency = 'EUR';
$ppusername = $_POST['custom'];
$fp = fsockopen ('sandbox.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp)
{
}
else
{
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp))
{
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
{
// When a payment has gone trough
    //When payment is 25EUR make it a month validity
    if ($ppusername&&($payment_currency=='EUR')&&($payment_amount=='25'))
    {
        $period = '+1 month';       
    }
    //When payment is 240EUR make it a year validity
    else if ($ppusername&&($payment_currency=='EUR')&&($payment_amount=='25'))
    {
        $period = '+1 year';        
    }
    //There is incorrect information in this payment
    else
    {

    }


    //Lets first get the date in mysql format
    $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());
    $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', strtotime("$date -7 hours"));
    //Now lets update the subscription records
    require_once('core/dbconnect.php');
    $subscriptionrecordexists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE username='$ppusername'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($subscriptionrecordexists))
    {
        //User has purchase before. Adjust his subscription record and ad an invoice.
        require_once('core/dbconnect.php');
        $subscriptionrecord = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE username='$ppusername'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($subscriptionrecord);
        //Update subscription record
        $currentvalidity = $row['validity'];
        if ($currentvalidity >= $date)
        {
            //Add period if subscription is still valid
            $newvalidity = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', strtotime("$currentvalidity $period"));
            require_once('core/dbconnect.php');
            mysql_query("UPDATE subscriptions SET validity='$newvalidity' WHERE username='$ppusername'");
            //Add invoice to user
            if ($period == '+1 month')
            {$product = 'NLTVMee.com voor 1 maand';}
            if ($period == '+1 year')
            {$product = 'NLTVMee.com voor 1 jaar';}
            $paymentmethode = 'Paypal';
            $oldvalid = $currentvalidity;
            $newvalid = $newvalidity;
            require_once('core/dbconnect.php');
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO invoices VALUES ('','$date','$ppusername','$product','$paymentmethode','$payment_currency','$payment_amount','$oldvalid','$newvalid')");
        }
        else
        {
            //Add period from current date if validity is not valid anymore
            $newvalidity = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', strtotime("$date $period"));
            require_once('core/dbconnect.php');
            mysql_query("UPDATE subscriptions SET validity='$newvalidity' WHERE username='$ppusername'");
            //Ad invoice to user
            if ($period == '+1 month')
            {$product = 'NLTVMee.com voor 1 maand';}
            if ($period == '+1 year')
            {$product = 'NLTVMee.com voor 1 jaar';}
            $paymentmethode = 'Paypal';
            $newvalid = $newvalidity;
            require_once('core/dbconnect.php');
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO invoices VALUES ('','$date','$ppusername','$product','$paymentmethode','$payment_currency','$payment_amount','','$newvalid')");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //User has never purchased before. Make new subscription record and add invoice.
        //Add period from current date if validity is not valid anymore
        $newvalidity = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', strtotime("$date $period"));
        require_once('core/dbconnect.php');
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO subscriptions VALUES ('','$ppusername','$newvalidity')");
        //Ad invoice to user
        if ($period == '+1 month')
        {$product = 'NLTVMee.com voor 1 maand';}
        if ($period == '+1 year')
        {$product = 'NLTVMee.com voor 1 jaar';}
        $paymentmethode = 'Paypal';
        $newvalid = $newvalidity;
        require_once('core/dbconnect.php');
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO invoices VALUES ('','$date','$ppusername','$product','$paymentmethode','$payment_currency','$payment_amount','','$newvalid')");
    }

}
//End
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0)
{

}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

As you can see it is now configured with the Paypal sandbox urls to try it out, but when I do and make the payment nothing is changed in the db and as you can see the IPN handler page should change things.

Comment: I forgot to add that these 2 parts of code are also on 2 different pages.

Answer (score 1):

It is a blank page because you have your ipn listener as your `return` value, which is where you are sent after completion, but no info is sent. The postback to Paypal will have no values and your code will fail.
([from the docs](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables) - *The URL to which PayPal redirects buyers' browser after they complete their payments. For example, specify a URL on your site that displays a "Thank you for your payment" page.*)

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mydomain.com/pp-ipn-handler.php">
```

You need to use [`notify_url`](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HF00TZS__id08A6I0980HH)
([from the docs](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables) - *The URL to which PayPal posts information about the payment, in the form of Instant Payment Notification messages.*)

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.mydomain.com/pp-ipn-handler.php">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mydomain.com/payment_complete_thank_message.php">
```

---

**Edit**
I see 3 additional errors in the code

Your query on line #65 is `$subscriptionrecord`, but on line #66 you are using `$userinfo`

```
    $subscriptionrecord = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE username='$ppusername'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($userinfo);
```

*Correction*
these below are not true as enclosing them in quotes `"$currentvalidity $period"` is the same as `$currentvalidity.$period`

On line #72 you need to concat `$currentvalidity` & `$period` inside `strtotime()` - `$currentvalidity.$period`

```
$newvalidity = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', strtotime("$currentvalidity $period"));
```

On line #91 & #111 you need to concat `$date` & `$period` inside `strtotime()` - `$date.$period`

```
$newvalidity = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', strtotime("$date $period"));
```

Comment: Still no luck. I have change the return value to the success url and then added the notify_url value to go to the ipn file as stated before.

It now goes to the success url as expected but the ipn handler still doesnt work as I have no records added to the database, so something still has to be wrong there.

Comment: It is putting me into the right direction though as obviously that is something I needed to add. Could you please look at the ipn handler code and see what is wrong to see why it doesn't respond to the information given by Paypal.

Comment: The first thing you can do is change the `header('Location: ppcommerror.php');` and `header('Location: ppsuccess.php');` to `mail(...)` or an [`error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), since this page/script will be run on the backend and no user will see it. This is similar to what I do. I will take a look, but I may not find anything else wrong based off what is here.

Comment: I have taken away the rerouting (header('Location...) lines now. But that still doesn't help. Thanks for taking another look.

Comment: I have found 3 additional issues in the code. I have added them to my answer under an **Edit**

Comment: I am very sorry for being a complete noob, but when you say concat I do not know exactly what you mean. The code below it is also exactly like the origional code. Could you please specify what you mean? Thanks a lot for helping me by the way. This problem has been driving me nuts for days...

Comment: concat is to add 2 variables together -ie. `$date.$period`. But I realized after I posted the edit that your `"$date $period"` is the same as `$date.$period`. So the only other issue I found was the `$subscriptionrecord`/`$userinfo`

Comment: Changed that (stupid mistake). But still no result. Something else is wrong.